# AWS Cloudfront CORS headers without S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront CDN to simply cache my static contents in "Origin Pull" mode. The CloudFront origin is my website.

However, I've encountered a CORS problem. My browser doesn't let my web pages load my fonts files and SVGs from CloudFront.

After googling this matter a bit, I noticed that all blogs/tutorials explain how to enable CORS on an S3 bucket used as the origin for CloudFront, and letting CloudFront forward the Access-Control-Allow-XXX headers from S3 to the client.

I don't need an S3 bucket and would like to keep it that way for the sake of simplicity, if possible.

Is it possible to enable CORS on CloudFront? Even a quick and dirty solution, such as setting the access control header on all responses would be good enough.

Comment: There is definitely no need for an S3 bucket, and there are a couple of different approaches you could use... but first, what is your origin server running as its internet-facing web server?  Nginx?  Apache?  Something else?  Is this something you have access to or is it fully outside your control?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - my internet-facing web server is an IIS with a nginx load balancer in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Following up the comment above, CORS is a request made FROM a domain different of the TO domain. The key part to avoid this, is in the server which returns your requests return the header allowing cross origin requests.

Your fonts, which should be your website's assets, should be kept in the same server as your website, therefore CORS should not be an issue.

Comment: The problem is that my fonts and SVGs are on the CDN network (accessed with URL cdn.MyWebsite.com), therefore my browser blocks the content.

Comment: Thats what your cloudfront is for. Add your cdn domain as another cloudfront origin and map the path in your application. If you are not sure how, add a comment and I will edit my answer with the steps.

Comment: I'm not sure how it makes sense to add the CDN domain as an origin. Isn't the origin the website where it should get the data from?

Comment: Please check: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/

Comment: The page seems to explain how to setup the use of S3 for static content. I do not want to use that.

I want Cloudfront to just serve the static content, so I can use a link like CDN.MyWebsite.com/img/img.jpg on my site, where CDN.MyWebSite.com is a CNAME to my Cloudfront URL.

Comment: CDN.MyWebsite.com will be your new origin. Then your will create a new behaviour with the patter img/* from CDN.MyWebsite.com/img
In your website, everytime your reach website.com/img it will pull the content from CDN.MyWebsite.com/img. You can change this name to assets/img if you prefer.

Comment: Cleriston, yes but the problem with that is CORS policy. I get a (blocked:origin) in Chrome. I assume I need to set some CORS headers in the response from Cloudfront, but how can I do that?

Comment: No you dont cause in your browser they all come from the "same" domain.